# error when using SKforecast : None of [Int64Index([48, ...],\n dtype='int64', name='date_time')] are in the [index]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

i have the dataset that i used the groupby(based on date and group) and the result is like this Dataframe:

```
| date        | group  | value |
|:----        |:------:| -----:|
| 2022-01-01  | 12    | 25.2|
| 2022-01-01  | 15    | 36.54|
| 2022-02-01  | 12    | 55.3|
| 2022-02-01  | 15    | 69.2|
```

and at the end i have 177 rows.

my first problem is that i can't apply data.asfreq

```
data = data.asfreq('MS')
```

i got this error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

my second problem is when i want to apply the xgboost i used this code:

```
data = data.set_index('date_time')
#data = data.asfreq('MS')
data = data.sort_index()

end_train = '2023-05-01'
end_validation = '2023-06-01'
data_train = data.loc[: end_train, :]
data_val   = data.loc[end_train:end_validation, :]
data_test  = data.loc[end_train:, :]

print(f"Dates train      : {data_train.index.min()} --- {data_train.index.max()}  (n={len(data_train)})")
print(f"Dates validacion : {data_val.index.min()} --- {data_val.index.max()}  (n={len(data_val)})")
print(f"Dates test       : {data_test.index.min()} --- {data_test.index.max()}  (n={len(data_test)})")

forecaster = ForecasterAutoreg(
                 regressor = XGBRegressor(random_state=123),
                 lags = 24
             )

# Regressor hyperparameters
param_grid = {
    'n_estimators': [100, 500],
    'max_depth': [3, 5, 10],
    'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.1]
}

# Lags used as predictors
lags_grid = [48, 72]

results_grid = grid_search_forecaster(
                   forecaster         = forecaster,
                   y                  = data.loc[:end_validation, 'value'], # Train and validation data
                   param_grid         = param_grid,
                   lags_grid          = lags_grid,
                   steps              = 36,
                   refit              = False,
                   metric             = 'mean_squared_error',
                   initial_train_size = len(data_train),
                   fixed_train_size   = False,
                   return_best        = True,
                   n_jobs             = 'auto',
                   verbose            = False
               )
```

i got this error :

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64,\n            65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81,\n            82, 83, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62,\n            63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76],\n           dtype='int64', name='date_time')] are in the [index]"
```

i tried to change lags_grid but i got almost the same error.
thanks in advance for any help.